# Compilation issues for Autodock GPU installation

Tags: linux, makefile

I am the definition of a beginner with Linux. I need to install Autodock GPU and I hit a wall when I reached the compilation stuff.

I was able to add the following environmental variables: GPU_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/lib64 as well as GPU_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/include. Furthermore, I was also able to add DEVICE=GPU. All of these show up when I use the "printenv" command.

However, I am unable to make "DEVICE=GPU" and the NUMWI one. Supposedly I need to make a makefile, which I have no idea how and I hoping to obtain some guidance today. There is also an option at I need to look for the makefile.CUDA. I don't know which one I should do or honestly how to do either.

I am in need of help.

Answer (score 0):

#### The makefile is included in the Autodock-GPU Github

So to install Autodock GPU there are three steps. First you need to set up the environment variables which you have already done.

Second, you need to clone the Autodock-GPU Github (after moving to a directory where you want to have it):

```
git clone https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-GPU
```

The makefile you need is included in there, so no need to create one yourself. You can just move to the directory you created when cloning the github repository.

```
cd Autodock-GPU
```

Third, you need to compile Autodock-GPU:

```
make DEVICE=GPU NUMWI=128
```